# What does "put something in control" mean?

Tags: meaning

> This product has capabilities that **put users in control** so that pre
>   and post document processing costs can be reduced.

Since "put something in control" means "take control of something", does it mean "the capabilities that have automation feature" so that it doesn't need users to control things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "put someone in control" means to give them the ability to make decisions that govern the behavior *of something*.

From context, what users are being put in control of is document processing, and so, presumably, they have control over one or more printers and/or photocopiers.

The sentence does not make clear precisely how the users are controlling document processing. Perhaps it might have to do with scheduling jobs on a slower printer or photocopier with a lower cost-per-page, or setting up a number of printers in a priority queue, so that jobs are routed to the least expensive printer available, or so that drafts are printed with a lower print quality requiring less ink.

Answer (score 0):

> Since "put something in control" means "take control of something"

That doesn't follow.  The former implies that *something* is doing the controlling, but the latter means that *something* is being controlled.

> This product has capabilities that put users in control

This just says that the user controls the product.

Comment: This is all correct but it's worth pointing out that the phrase implies that prior to this product, users *were not* in control.